# How to make a floating point number in Unity from BigInteger? The BigDecimal library does not work

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I create a clicker in Unity and use BigInteger to save money, but when creating a game economy (prices for goods), I realized that I need to use decimal or double so that there are two more digits after the decimal point (like this: 12.34) .I tried to include the BigDecimal libraries from NuGet but Unity does not support them. I tried to change my number formating method somehow, but it didn't work. What should I do? Thanks in advance!
My method:

```
public string FormatMoney(BigInteger value)
    {
        BigInteger[] divisors = {
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 3),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 6),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 9),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 12),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 15),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 18),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 21),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 24),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 27),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 30),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 33),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 36),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 39),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 42),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 45),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 48),
            BigInteger.Pow(10, 52)
        };

        string[] suffixes = {"K", "M", "B", "T", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ah", "ai", "aj", "ak", "al" };

        if (value < 1000)
        {
            return value.ToString("N0");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < divisors.Length; i++)
        {
            if (value < divisors[i] * 1000)
            {
                decimal formattedValue = (decimal)value / (decimal)divisors[i];
                formattedValue = decimal.Truncate(formattedValue * 100) / 100;
                return $"{formattedValue:F2}{suffixes[i]}";
            }
        }

        int lastIndex = divisors.Length - 1;
        decimal finalFormattedValue = (decimal)value / (decimal)divisors[lastIndex];
        finalFormattedValue = decimal.Truncate(finalFormattedValue * 100) / 100;
        return $"{finalFormattedValue:F2}{suffixes[lastIndex]}";
    }
```

Comment: Multiply by 100 when you create the big integer and then divide by 100 when you need the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
public static string GetStringValue(BigInteger target, int places){
    return target.ToString("F" + places, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: this will most probably always result in `XY.00`, wouldn't it ;)